# Display Correct Div based on Radio Button Checked

Tags: javascript, beginner, jquery

We are using a plugin for our WordPress website. I'm trying to add some custom code to it and finally got it working however it is ultra janky. The HTML is a simplified version of the actual site's but it's the JQuery I need help with. I'm trying to trim as much fat as I possibly can. I'm am not the greatest with JQuery but know enough to stumble and get by.

The goal is when the page loads is to check if the radio group has an option checked and to then display the correct one and hide the rest. The same goes for when someone changes that option however it now needs to uncheck any other option they might have already checked for the previous one. I'm looking for help to condense this down while having this work the way it currently is. Unfortunately I can not go based off other attributes except for name and value. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

HTML:

```
<div>
    <label>Oak</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='Oak_0' checked="checked">

    <label>Brown Maple</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='Brown Maple_1'>

    <label>Cherry</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='Cherry_2'>

    <label>Quartersawn White Oak</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='Quartersawn White Oak_3'>

    <label>Hard Maple</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='Hard Maple_4'>

    <label>Hickory</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='Hickory_5'>

    <!-- Many Others... -->
</div>
<div class="stains-container">
  <div class="oak-stains-div">
    <h4>Oak</h4>
    <label>Michael's Cherry</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <label>Rich Tobacco</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <label>Dark Knight</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <!-- Many Others... -->
  </div>
  <div class="b-maple-stains-div">
    <h4>Brown Maple</h4>
    <label>Michael's Cherry</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <label>Rich Tobacco</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <label>Dark Knight</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <!-- Many Others... -->
  </div>
  <div class="cherry-stains-div">
    <h4>Cherry</h4>
    <label>Michael's Cherry</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <label>Rich Tobacco</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <label>Dark Knight</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <!-- Many Others... -->
  </div>
  <div class="qswo-stains-div">
    <h4>Quartersawn White Oak</h4>
    <label>Michael's Cherry</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <label>Rich Tobacco</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <label>Dark Knight</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <!-- Many Others... -->
  </div>
  <div class="h-maple-stains-div">
    <h4>Hard Maple</h4>
    <label>Michael's Cherry</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <label>Rich Tobacco</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <label>Dark Knight</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <!-- Many Others... -->
  </div>
  <div class="hickory-stains-div">
    <h4>Hickory</h4>
    <label>Michael's Cherry</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <label>Rich Tobacco</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <label>Dark Knight</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <!-- Many Others... -->
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
// Create Variables
    var stains = $(".stains-container");
    // Check if Oak is checked
    var $oakchecked = $("input.b-maple-stains, input.cherry-stains, input.qswo-stains, input.h-maple-stains, input.hickory-stains");
    var $oakactive = $(".b-maple-stains-div li, .cherry-stains-div li, .qswo-stains-div li, .h-maple-stains-div li, .hickory-stains-div li");
    // Check if B. Maple is checked
    var $bmaplechecked = $("input.oak-stains, input.cherry-stains, input.qswo-stains, input.h-maple-stains, input.hickory-stains");
    var $bmapleactive = $(".oak-stains-div li, .cherry-stains-div li, .qswo-stains-div li, .h-maple-stains-div li, .hickory-stains-div li");
    // Check if Cherry is checked
    var $cherrychecked = $("input.oak-stains, input.b-maple-stains, input.qswo-stains, input.h-maple-stains, input.hickory-stains");
    var $cherryactive = $(".oak-stains-div li, .b-maple-stains-div li, .qswo-stains-div li, .h-maple-stains-div li, .hickory-stains-div li");
    // Check if QSWO is checked
    var $qswochecked = $("input.oak-stains, input.b-maple-stains, input.cherry-stains, input.h-maple-stains, input.hickory-stains");
    var $qswoactive = $(".oak-stains-div li, .b-maple-stains-div li, .cherry-stains-div li, .h-maple-stains-div li, .hickory-stains-div li");
    // Check if H. Maple is checked
    var $hmaplechecked = $("input.oak-stains, input.b-maple-stains, input.cherry-stains, input.qswo-stains, input.hickory-stains");
    var $hmapleactive = $(".oak-stains-div li, .b-maple-stains-div li, .cherry-stains-div li, .qswo-stains-div li, .hickory-stains-div li");
    // Check if Hickory is checked
    var $hickorychecked = $("input.oak-stains, input.b-maple-stains, input.cherry-stains, input.qswo-stains, input.h-maple-stains");
    var $hickoryactive = $(".oak-stains-div li, .b-maple-stains-div li, .cherry-stains-div li, .qswo-stains-div li, .h-maple-stains-div li");


// Check if a button is pre-selected and if its value matches
var radio_buttons = $("input[name='tmcp_radio_0']");
    if( radio_buttons.is(":checked") && /^Oak_\d$/.test($(this).val())) {
        alert("OAK is selected");
        $(".oak-stains-div").show();
        $oakchecked.prop('checked', false);
        $oakactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
    } else if( radio_buttons.is(":checked") && /^Brown Maple_\d$/.test($(this).val())) {
        alert("B MAPLE is selected");
        $(".b-maple-stains-div").show();
        $bmaplechecked.prop('checked', false);
        $bmapleactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
    } else if( radio_buttons.is(":checked") && /^Cherry_\d$/.test($(this).val())) {
        alert("CHERRY is selected");
        $(".cherry-stains-div").show();
        $cherrychecked.prop('checked', false);
        $cherryactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
    } else if( radio_buttons.is(":checked") && /^Quartersawn White Oak_\d$/.test($(this).val())) {
        alert("QSWO is selected");
        $(".qswo-stains-div").show();
        $qswochecked.prop('checked', false);
        $qswoactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
    } else if( radio_buttons.is(":checked") && /^Hard Maple_\d$/.test($(this).val())) {
        alert("H MAPLE is selected");
        $(".h-maple-stains-div").show();
        $hmaplechecked.prop('checked', false);
        $hmapleactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
    } else if( radio_buttons.is(":checked") && /^Hickory_\d$/.test($(this).val())) {
        alert("HICKORY is selected");
        $(".hickory-stains-div").show();
        $hickorychecked.prop('checked', false);
        $hickoryactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
    } else if( radio_buttons.is(":not(:checked)")) {
        alert("NOTHING is selected");
        $(".stains-container").hide();
    } 
    // Check if Oak is selected or pre-selected
    radio_buttons.on('change',function(){
        if ( /^Oak_\d$/.test($(this).val())) {
            stains.show();
            $(".oak-stains-div").show();
            $oakchecked.prop('checked', false);
            $oakactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
        }  else {
            $(".oak-stains-div").hide();
        }
    });

    // Check if B. Maple is selected or pre-selected
    radio_buttons.on('change',function(){
        if ( /^Brown Maple_\d$/.test($(this).val())) {
            stains.show();
            $(".b-maple-stains-div").show();
            $bmaplechecked.prop('checked', false);
            $bmapleactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
        } else {
            $(".b-maple-stains-div").hide();
        }
    });

    // Check if Cherry is selected or pre-selected
    radio_buttons.on('change',function(){
        if ( /^Cherry_\d$/.test($(this).val())) {
            stains.show();
            $(".cherry-stains-div").show();
            $cherrychecked.prop('checked', false);
            $cherryactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
        } else {
            $(".cherry-stains-div").hide();
        }
    });

    // Check if QSWO is selected or pre-selected
    radio_buttons.on('change',function(){
        if ( /^Quartersawn White Oak_\d$/.test($(this).val())) {
            stains.show();
            $(".qswo-stains-div").show();
            $qswochecked.prop('checked', false);
            $qswoactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
        } else {
            $(".qswo-stains-div").hide();
        }
    });

    // Check if Hard Maple is selected or pre-selected
    radio_buttons.on('change',function(){
        if ( /^Hard Maple_\d$/.test($(this).val())) {
            stains.show();
            $(".h-maple-stains-div").show();
            $hmaplechecked.prop('checked', false);
            $hmapleactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
        } else {
            $(".h-maple-stains-div").hide();
        }
    });

    // Check if Hickory is selected or pre-selected
    radio_buttons.on('change',function(){
        if ( /^Hickory_\d$/.test($(this).val())) {
            stains.show();
            $(".hickory-stains-div").show();
            $hickorychecked.prop('checked', false);
            $hickoryactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
        } else {
            $(".hickory-stains-div").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/amishdirect/h94c7rsw/7/